# Mock class used in a method Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I am using mockk Kotlin library. I have a service Service that has a private method calling a 3d party client

```
class Service {
  fun foo() {
    bar()
  }
  
  private fun bar() {
    client = Client()
    client.doStuff()
  }
}
```

Now in my test I need to mock Client, e.g.

```
@Test
fun `my func does what I expect` {

}
```

I need to also mock what doStuff returns. How do I achieve this in Kotlin mockk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you should never instantiate a dependency like `Client` **inside** your service class since you cannot access it to provide a Mock.  Let's deal with that first...

```kotlin
class Client { // this is the real client
    fun doStuff(): Int {
        // access external system/file/etc
        return 777
    }
}

class Service(private val client: Client) {
    fun foo() {
        bar()
    }

    private fun bar() {
        println(client.doStuff())
    }
}
```

and then this how to use Mockk

```kotlin
class ServiceTest {
    private val client: Client = mockk()

    @Test
    fun `my func does what I expect`() {
        every { client.doStuff() } returns 666
        val service = Service(client)
        service.foo()
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the Client class needs to be instantiate on every call of the function, because its constructor need some parameter passed from the bar function?

Comment: Think about the mocked class (Client) not how it works internally, but how it seems to work externally.  With that in mind you would then use the mockk feature that you can specify the output of Client under certain circumstances.  So if in one test you need Client.doStuff to return 777 but another time 88 this is how you'd do that:

every { client.doStuff()) } return 777
or
every { client.doStuff()) } return 888

You can make the return dynamic too... next read about `answers`